# write border in shorthand !

Tags: html, css, shorthand

i am using border on object.
like

```
.box{
    border-left:solid 1px #000;
    border-right:solid 1px #000;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #000;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

may i write this in shorthand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This saves only one line:

```
border: 1px solid #000;
border-top: 0;
```

Comment: And after saving all those characters, you could splash out and use `black` instead of `#000`!

Comment: Indeed, go on and splurge! You deserve it!

Comment: is there not way to write this in 1 line? like we use in margin and padding?

Comment: No. Margin/padding doesn't have to suffer from color/style. Consider GZIP if those extra bytes really cares you.

Comment: @kc rajput : You have shorthand for border-width, which is what difers: `border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;` or even `border-width: 0px 1px 1px;` - see http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/border-width/ . But no, there is no shorthand for defining what you want with a single line... it would be a huge and confusing line.

Comment: @ANeves: `border-width` does essentially the same as `border` without color/style. `border: 0px 1px 1px`. You saves 6 characters! Oh, even more if you use `0` instead of `0px`. It's all doable.